# How would I align text above and below a line while keeping the line centered?

Tags: css

I'm creating a timeline in css that overflows if content is too long. I have text above and below the timeline where each segment is equal to the width of the text.

I've played around with both `absolute` and `relative` positioning.

The issue with `absolute position` is that I can't set the width of each segment to the text, which causes issues when the width of the viewport is smaller than the cumulative text.

The issue with `relative position` is that the text and the segment is all centered as a whole, which doesn't center the segment perfectly.

Before this I used `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` and set the segment to the parent element. The issue with this is that now my height has to be set manually since the height of the element is tied to the segment, and not the child text.

```html
<div class="timeline">
    <div class="segment">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <ul>
            <li>list</li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

```
.timeline
    display                     flex
    flex-wrap                   nowrap
    align-items                 center
    width                       100%
    .segment
        flex                    auto
        white-space             nowrap
        display                 flex
        flex-direction          column
        .line
            height              0.1rem
            background-color    black
```

I expect:

```
    x      x      x
⬤⸻⬤⸻⬤⸻⬤
  y      y      y
         y
```

But I get this instead (roughly speaking):

```
    x       x      x
⬤______⬤⸻⬤______⬤
  y       y       y
          y
```

Comment: That’s not actualy CSS. Please provide a [mre] of your issue, that can easily be reproduced by everyone here without the need for any additional components. Ideally with some actual content so we can see the effect you are talking about; your ASCII art with the x and y isn’t that helpful to begin with IMHO.

Comment: We should also know if your titles (`x` in the example) can take multiple lines (or have different line-height) as `y` does (is it enough to align to the top?)

Comment: Are the `li` items each group of  `x` and `y` values or do they represent each individual `x` and `y` value? Are the dots in your design supposed to be the dots which accompany the `li` default style or dots of your own implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure how your code is set up but I believe the issue is with the uneven list items. This can happen when you use display flex with an uneven amount of items in a `ul` element.

I changed the display for `.timeline` from `display: flex` to `display: inline-block`, which is safer for displaying uneven lists, as well as the display for `.segment` from `display: flex` to `display: inline-flex`.

You should also consider using `inline-flex` for items that you want to have a display of `flex` but remain inline.

Please see the snippit below.

```css
.timeline{
    display:                     inline-block;
    align-items:                 center;
    width:                       100%;
}
.segment{
        width:200px;
        display: inline-flex;
        white-space:             nowrap;
        flex-direction:          column;
}

.line{
            height:              0.1rem;
            background-color:    black;   
}

.timeline > div:nth-child(even) > .list {
  position: absolute;
}

/* UNCOMMENT BELOW TO SEE ORIGINAL CSS*/
/* .timeline{
    display:                     flex;
    flex-wrap:                   nowrap;
    align-items:                 center;
    width:                       100%;
}
.segment{
        flex:                    auto;
        white-space:             nowrap;
        display:                 flex;
        flex-direction:          column;
}
.line{
            height:              0.1rem;
            background-color:    black;   
} */
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
    <div class="segment">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <ul class='list'>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="segment">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <ul class='list'>
          <li>y</li>
          <li>y</li>
          <li>y</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="segment">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <ul class='list'>
          <li>y</li>
         
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I added

```
 .timeline > div:nth-child(even) > .list {
    position: absolute;
 }
```

To give you a quick fix for displaying every second list item above the lines, keeping the odd lists below.

As you didn't provide all of your code I cannot make the replication exactly like your use case but the phenomenon is the same and this should help you achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to set `align-items: start;`. If need to center all that vertically in a container, you can wrap everything into a `div` that will be centered.

If you need to have different sized titles, you can set fixed `line-height` and `margin`.

```css
.timeline {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: start;
  width: 100%;
}

.segment {
  flex: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.segment h1{
  line-height: 38px;
  margin: 21px 0;
}

.line {
  height: 0.1rem;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
    <div class="segment">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <ul>
            <li>list</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="segment">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <ul>
            <li>list</li>
            <li>list</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="segment">
        <h1 style="font-size: 20px;">title</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <ul>
            <li>list</li>
            <li>list</li>
            <li>list</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```